# Chrome extensions interacting with Progressive Web Apps (PWA)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, progressive-web-apps

Does anyone know if it's possible for a Chrome extension to interact with a PWA? Since a PWA installed by Chrome seems to be just a Chrome wrapper for the web application, perhaps Google still allows extensions to interact with the PWA.

Comment: I am also looking for this. Because of https://superuser.com/a/667522/493277

Comment: It seems possible: https://dev.to/chromiumdev/shipping-pwas-as-chrome-extensions-3l5c though in that case the extension basically _is_ the PWA